# Remove text between the tags using regular expression in notepad

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I have following xml tags:
`<EmployerName>company name</EmployerName>` and `<Email>name@gmail.com</Email>`

I am using the following regular expression-
`<EmployerName>[0-9A-Z:-]*</EmployerName>` to remove the data between tags. But, the data is not getting removed. Any idea?

Comment: There is a space in `company name`, but you don't match this in your character class - so what would you expect?

Comment: I want to remove all words between the tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to match everything within the tags, just use `.`:

```
<EmployerName>.*</EmployerName>
```

Your character group `[0-9A-Z:-]` covers digits, letters, the colon and the hyphen characters, but it doesn't include whitespace or other special characters.

Then you can replace with simply `<EmployerName></EmployerName>`.

In case there are multiple `EmployerName` elements on the same line, use a reluctant match:

```
<EmployerName>.*?</EmployerName>
```

Comment: So using .* I can replace anything between tags?

Comment: @user2961127 Yes did you try it?

Comment: But be careful if the EmployerName tag exists multiple times in a single line ;)

Comment: yeah i tried. it is working fine. thanks both of you

Comment: this won't match if there is linebreak in tag content

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is missing the space “company name”. Try replacing the following:

```
(<\/?(?:EmployerName|Email)>)[a-z \.@]+(<\/?(?:EmployerName|Email)>)
```

… with `$1$2`. Backreferencing didn’t work in Notepad++, so it’s a little verbose.

Answer (score 0):

```
<EmployerName>[^<]*</EmployerName>
```

The working [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aK7pD2/2)